# How to calculate web view content height in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I need to resize the web view frame according to content height. So I need to calculate the height of content.

Comment: Already solution has been provided a this [link].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540050/uiwebview-resize-height-to-fit-content

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the content height of a UIWebView in iPhone sdk, objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837214/how-to-get-the-content-height-of-a-uiwebview-in-iphone-sdk-objective-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution that i use

```
NSUInteger contentHeight = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"]] intValue];
```

Your webview should have a frame smaller than all possible content size

Comment: Important to know: I had a lot of issues using this on a certain piece of html/css from a 3rd party. After searching I came to the conclusion that you can get into trouble when the html contains viewport-relative sizing in its CSS. The typical "make 0 pixels high, render webview, query height, set webview height to result" does not work, because if e.g. a font-size is defined as 3.4vh the text will change size when you increase the webview height, invalidating the result of your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
        NSLog(@"Content Size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(contentSize));
    }
```